# How to proxy RDP via Nginx

Tags: nginx, remote-desktop, rdp

I'm using the below config in nginx to proxy RDP connection:

```
  server { 
    listen          80;
    server_name     domain.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://192.168.0.100:3389;
    }
  }
```

but the connection doesn't go through. My guess is that the problem is `http` in `proxy_pass`. Googling "Nginx RDP" didn't yield much.

Anyone knows if it's possible and if yes how?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well actually you are right the `http` is the problem but not exactly that one in your code block. Lets explain it a bit:

In your `nginx.conf` file you have something similar to this:

```
http {  
    ...
    ...
    ...

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

So everything you write in your conf files are inside this `http` block/scope. But **rdp** is not **http** is a different protocol.

The only workaround I know for nginx to handle this is to work on `tcp` level.

So inside in your `nginx.conf` and outside the `http` block you have to declare the `stream` block like this:

```
stream {
    # ...
    server {
        listen     80;
        proxy_pass 192.168.0.100:3389;
    }
}
```

With the above configuration just proxying your backend on tcp layer with a cost of course. As you may notice its missing the `server_name` attribute you can't use it in the `stream` scope, plus you lose all the logging functionality that comes on the `http` level.

For more info on this topic check the [docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/)

Comment: Appreciate your answer. I read that RDP can now be used in combination with HTTPS. That gives me the impression that we can use it inside `http` block as SSL connection. But cuz of my limited knowledge on this matter, I can't see how that's potentially possible. What are your thoughts?

Comment: This is the line in the below article that made me think this way: "Essentially, standard RPC traffic is wrapped in HTTPS at the client"

http://www.brianmadden.com/opinion/Its-Official-Microsoft-is-Adding-an-RDP-over-HTTPS-Proxy-to-Windows

Comment: Well the line you quoted is referring to an application (outlook) which wraps the RPC in HTTPS and on the other side you have another software which can handle the unpacked message. Microsoft has developed software with which packs and unpacks RDP on https traffic, of course nginx can't do this. You need a different implementation for this you can't deliver directly to port 3389 you need a RD Gateway check this https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-Remote-Desktop-to-a-Terminal-Server-via-a-Web-Proxy

Comment: For what its worth, if you change the ports this syntax works for VNC as well

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a config that is complete and doesn't contain a bunch of dots **that would never pass an nginx config test**, below is a complete and tested configuration.

This example listens on port `25301` and forwards connection to `rds.example.com:25301`. Then in your wireless router, you must forward incoming connections on port `25301` to target Windows PC IP address & port `3389`.

#### Port Forwarding — Router Setup

| Service Name | External Port | Internal Port | Internal IP Address | Protocol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SERVER9_RDP | 25301 | 3389 | 10.0.0.9 | BOTH |

#### NGINX — RDP Config

```
stream {
    tcp_nodelay            on;
    resolver               1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout       5s;

    server {
        listen 25301;
        # proxy_pass 192.168.0.1:25301;
        proxy_pass rds.example.com:25301;

        proxy_connect_timeout 10s;
        proxy_timeout 2h;
        # Preserve client IP address
        proxy_bind $remote_addr transparent;

        allow 192.168.1.0/24;  # Example for allowing specific IPs
        deny all;

        # Logging
        access_log             off;
        error_log              /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking to load balance RDP connection using Nginx, here is what I did:

Configure nginx as you normally would, to reroute HTTP(S) traffic to your desired server.

On that server, install [myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille) (it needs IIS and .Net 4.5) and you'll be able to RDP into your server from a browser!